# how to write encoded stream in JSON and retrieve back in ajax?

Tags: java, json, ajax, base64, bufferedinputstream

I am geeting image in input stream and encoding it into base64 and sending it to client using JSON
Following is code snippet.

Server side :

```
 JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
    StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int ch =0; ;        
    sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder= new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    byte[] contents = new byte[5000000];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    String strFileContents;
    while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
        responseStrBuilder.append(encoder.encode(contents).getBytes());
    }
    myObj.addProperty("1",responseStrBuilder.toString());
    out.println(myObj.toString());
```

Client side ajax code :

```
success: function(result)
           {
            if(result)

            {
                $('#dynamicCamping01').html('<img src='+result[Object.keys(result)[0]]+'/>');
                $('#dynamicCampingDesc01').html("<h3>"+allData[0]+"</h3>");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Something went wrong while retriving events");
            }
```

getting data at client side but image is not displaying.

Comment: Debugging, Step 1: If you use a browser or command-line tool (like wget or curl) to go directly to your ajax URL, do you get the json you expect?  If no, you have a server-side issue.  If yes, you have a client-side issue.

Comment: @JohnHascall got the data in client in base64 format but still image is not displaying

Here is my code of ajax : -

if (jqXHR.readyState == 4) {
           $('#dynamicCamping01').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"'+jqXHR.reresponseText+'"/> ');
              $('#dynamicCampingDesc01').html("<h3>"+allData[0]+"</h3>");
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked :

```
   BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  

    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
    int ch =0; ;  

    sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder= new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    byte[] contents = new byte[5000000];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    String strFileContents;
    while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
        bout.write(encoder.encode(contents).getBytes());
    }
    bout.close();
    fin.close();
    bin.close();
    out.close();
```

and main important part is on client converting image into UTF-8 and Base64 decoding.

```
$(imageIDSData[i]).html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,'+imageData[i]+'"/> ');
    $(imageNameIDSData[i]).html("<h3>"+allData[i]+"</h3>");
```